# How to display Image data type in blob field in Crystal Report 9

Tags: sql-server, image, vb6, blob, crystal-reports-8.5

I'm working with Crystal report 9. I have some QR Codes in my database (SQL Server 2012) in as IMAGE datatype.

I'm getting the data using stored procedure, everything is working fine except the image which is not showing in the Crystal Report blob field.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: `image` has been deprecated since *at least* 2005, you should really be using `varbinary(MAX)` by now.

Comment: CR 8.5 was released in 2001, 9 was a year later - highly doubtful you are using that version.

Comment: Suggest you review [this SAP answer](https://answers.sap.com/questions/185364/unable-to-load-image-from-database-or-path-unto-a-.html) for general how-to. But ancient versions of CR might not have this functionality

Comment: @SMor I know it's too old for now, but this is not mine, my client is using this and he doesn't want to update his technology either.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Larnu but even varbinary(max) isn't working.

Comment: My point was that you shouldn't be using that data type anymore, however, it sounds like you're using an even older version of Crystal Reports, and that's the first problem you should be addressing.

Comment: BLOB fileds should work okay if it contains a valid Crystal Reports image type.  For example BMP and JPG will be okay, but GIF is not supported.